# I would like to build a delay circuit

Tags: relay, inverter, control, trigger

I would like to build a latching relay control circuit, controlled by MCU.
I'd like to implement the following:
[image]
The idea is from here: https://pdfserv.maximintegrated.com/en/an/AN3288.pdf
The relay I would use is omron G6CU-2117P-US DC3
Datasheet: https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2976880.pdf
The latching relay's critical point is to return to steady state after it was switched. For the control I would use max4820 relay control circuit, however for the return to zero current I would use hardware which resets the max4820 ic, once the switch is done.
I thought the following curcuit:
[image]
Pulse would came to this circuit, when CS goes high on max4820
First schmitt would be a pulse detector for 1us, the second would function as a holder (monostable multivibrator). Making C2 and R2 high enough (with T about 30-50 ms) would serve as a power on reset circuit as well, and the final output pulse detector would be the output which would send the -RESET (about 1us) to the max4820.

Dou you thing this would do the job?
If not could you please suggest a better solution?
Thank you.

Comment: What latching relay are you considering (data sheet link please)? What do you mean by: *The latching relay's critical point is to return to steady state after it was switched*? I think you need to show the rest of the schematic involving the MAX4820 and, you need to link the MAX4820 device data sheet into your question. Why can't your MCU GPIO replace the circuit you have shown?

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. It's slightly unclear what the operations are, please can you edit your question and make the descriptions of each step of operation more distinct and separate. From a first glance though, have you looked at doing this with a 555 timer?

Comment: If you have a MCU then why do you need external timers? Is the MCU clock too inaccurate or what?

Comment: Thank you for the answers. Nope, MCU is accurate enough, but the software could go wrong sometimes, or just simple freeze. That's why I would not trust the mcu for controlling this. If the lathing relays would have current for long enough time, it would burn. I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: Yes, it's a very valid safety reason for not using the MCU. It must be done properly though so the final circuit doesn't have the vulnerabilities of the MCU-only circuit, otherwise it's just expenditure with no reliability improvement. If this ever needs actual safety approvals, you'll need that further analysis and justification on your solution.

Comment: The relays you have linked are not "latching relays"; they are just conventional relays as far as I can tell. I think the confusion here comes from you using the term "latching relays". Where does the reset pulse come from?

Comment: Hello Andy,
The relays datasheet includes multiple relays, on page 8 there are the latching ones, especially 117p type. I would go with that one. The application note (AN3288) also says that max4820 is capable of control 4 latching relays. So I definitely would like to go with lathing relays.
The only question would be: Does this delay circuit capable of ressetting the relays (via the relay control chip max4820), can it go wrong somewhere? (e.g. not sending the reset pulse for some reason), because I don't trust in the mcu doing the reset. The reset pulse goes to the max4820 -RESET pin.